# Image warping with Python

Tags: python, image-processing

I need to warp an image of relatively large size (1679x1475) in Python. I have the transformed coordinates. How can I efficiently warp the image to transformed coordinate system. I tried scipy.interpolate.griddata, but soon my computer runs out of memory.

Answer (score 6):

You want [scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates.html). You can configure the interpolation method and how it handles points that are outside the original image.
An example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc
#create a 2D array that has a grayscale image of a raccoon
face = misc.face(gray=True)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(face,cmap=plt.cm.gray)
```

[the unwarped image looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvUri.png)

```
#set up our new coordinate system
rows,cols = np.mgrid[0:768, 0:1024]
rows = rows**(1/2) * 767**(1/2)
cols = cols**(2) / 1023
rows = np.roll(rows,150,0)

from scipy import ndimage
#warp the image using a 3rd order (cubic) spline interpolation
new_img = ndimage.map_coordinates(face,[rows,cols], order=3)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(new_img,cmap=plt.cm.gray)
```

[the image after warping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBbNH.png)